# Change variable attribute name

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I want to change attribute names with variables. However, I can't wrap my head around how to access just the constant. In the following example, I want to change all attribute names starting with "monkey" and change them to "banana", but leave the dashes and numbers unchanged.

Change the following:

```
<div monkey-20="delicious" monkey-100="delicious">
```

To this:

```
<div banana-20="delicious" banana-100="delicious">
```

Anyone have tips?

Comment: `$('div').attr('banana-20', $('div').attr('monkey-20')); $('div').removeAttr('monkey-20');`?

Comment: I recommend using the html5 `data` attribute instead. eg <div data-banana-20="delicious" data-banana-100="delicious"></div>

Comment: @putvande methods can be chained to avoid useless dom traversal .. `var $div = $('div'); $div.each(function(){var t = $(this); t.attr('banana-20', (t.attr('monkey-20') || '')).removeAttr('monkey-20');});`

Comment: I should have mentioned: there are going to be cases where there are multiple attributes with varying numbers. I want to change all attribute names starting with "monkey" and change them to "banana", but leave the dashes and numbers unchanged.

Comment: Do you need to use Attributes or can you add Child elements like `<div data-cat="monkey" data-num="20" data-val="delicious"/>` to your div?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the category and the number attached to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could argue that your specific requirement to change attribute names is somewhat unusual, so a somewhat unorthodox solution in the form of a jQuery plug-in might work for you:

```
$.fn.renameAttrs = function() {
  var oldName = arguments[0] + '-',
      newName = arguments[1] + '-';

  return this.each(function() {
    var $node = $(this),
        attrs = [];

    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
      var index = this.name.indexOf(oldName);

      if (!index) {
        $node.attr(newName + this.name.substr(oldName.length), this.value);
        attrs.push(this);
      }
    });

    $.each(attrs, function() {
      $node.removeAttr(this.name);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Your argument is totally valid: unfortunately, the project is very specific, so your solution may actually be perfect for its requirements! I've added the function but am I calling it correctly in this example: http://play.meyouand.us/140409-renameattr/rename-attr1.html

Comment: @MarcP Yes you are, but in that example you'll need to call the plug-in function on DOM ready, e.g. `$(function() { $('div').renameAttrs('monkey', 'banana'); })`;